# How to load multiple tables at once in the power query editor?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Lets say I've 6 tables in "workbook1" and in different sheets, wanna load them into power query editor. But do not want to create a new workbook and then import "workbook1".

Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please back up this Workbook1 first, then open this workbook, go to Data tab > Get & Transform Data group > Get Data > From File > From Excel Workbook.

Browse and import Workbook1 > Tick the box of "Select multiple items" and choose the 6 tables > Transform Data.

[image]